# Conditional eax != 0 and edx == 0?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, conditional-statements, nasm

I have a example code like this :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

div eax
int 0x80
```

after I compile and run it, the output is :

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

My question is :

1. whether this is conditional on the `eax != 0 and eax == 0` ?
2. what the purpose of `Floating point exception (core dumped)` ?

Comment: re:2: See [this Q&A for background on SIGFPE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio) for integer division.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name is a bit misleading, as you have no floating point arithmetic in your code snippet.

In C, division by zero is undefined behavior, which means you can't portably assume a specific behavior (or more correctly, you have to expect that *anything* could happen).

On the x86, that anything is a hardware exception. One of the main responsibilities of an operating system is handling these hardware exceptions. Linux handles a division by zero by signalling `SIGFPE` to the offending process.

Most processes can't continue running after a division by zero (Because really what value should the program continue with?) and thus dump core and abort with a return value indicative of the signal that made it abort.

Your shell then interpreted the return value of your pogram and wrote `Floating point exception (core dumped)` on your terminal.

It doesn't have to be always like that though. Virtual machines like Java's have a handler for divison by zero that throws a java-specific `ArithmeticException` instead, that you can handle without aborting your program.

In your code, the division by zero was because your uninitialized `eax` had a zero in it.

Comment: `div` also faults if `%[r/e]dx` (the high half of the dividend) is greater than or equal to the divisor, because the quotient doesn't fit into a register.

Comment: If the executable was dynamically linked (`gcc nasm-output.o`), then the dynamic linker runs before `_start` and will leave garbage in some registers, including `edx`.  Linux does zero all non-ABI-defined registers in a freshly-`exec`ced process, though, to avoid leaking kernel information, so divide-by-zero is the other major possibility for sure.