# Assembly division returns non-number

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, i386

I tried writing my first, very simple program in Assembly. It is supposed to take two digits as input and perform addition, subtraction, multiplication and division on it. I currently do not care about how the program performs when you enter numbers like 5 and 5 (the sum and product of which wouldn't display correctly), cause I'm still learning, and will get to expanding the program further later. Right now, everything works like a charm, except division. When inputting 4 and 2, it, for example, returns the letter 'r' under the quotient. The code that should do this is:

```
;lastly, division

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov ecx, msg6
mov edx, len6
int 0x80

mov ax, [num1]
sub ax, '0'

mov ebx, [num2]
sub ebx, '0'

div ebx
add al, '0'

add ah, '0' ;in case there is a remainder

mov [quot], al
mov [rem], ah

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov ecx, quot
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov ecx, spacer
mov edx, len8
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov ecx, msg7
mov edx, len7
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STDOUT
mov ecx, rem
mov edx, 1
int 0x80
```

Just for the record, `msg6` is just the message: "The quotient is: " and `msg7` is the message "The remainder is: ". `num1` and `num2` are the input numbers. `spacer` is my way of inputting spacing between the results. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can provide an MCVE then I might be tempted to run your program and see what the problem is.  Also did you step through every line with gdb while looking at register values?

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but I don't know what MCVE and gdb are. As I said, I have only begun to learn assembly today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `div ebx` is `edx:eax/ebx` with quotient in `eax` and remainder in `edx`.

Comment: Clear EDX before DIV.

Comment: So, should I use `bl` as the divisor instead of ebx?

Comment: See my response to the answer below.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: In comments, `[mcve]` expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
div   ebx
```

divides `ebx` by `eax`, and puts the remainder in `edx`.  This is because ebx is a 4 byte divisor.

You seem to be expecting the remainder in `ah`.  I believe you'll get what you want if you use

```
div   bl
```

since `bl` is a 1 byte divisor.  For 1 byte divisors the result goes in `al` and the remainder in `ah`.  See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic.

EDIT:

As some have mentioned, you must clear the destination for the remainder in advance, `edx` for the 4-byte case, and `ah` for the 1-byte case.

Comment: From Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 2: *DIV r/m32 [...] Unsigned divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with
result stored in EAX ← Quotient, EDX ←
Remainder.*

Comment: I tried doing that, but now I get a `Floating Point Error` and the rest of the code does not execute. Again, testing on the case of numbers 4 and 2, so I don't see why there would be any floats involved.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to clear the high part of the dividend prior to the division. In the case of `div ebx` that would be `edx`, and in the case of `div bl` it would be `ah`. See _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual_, which describes the `DIV` instruction and all other x86/x86-64 instructions.

Comment: Assuming I properly cleared the `ah` register (with `mov ah, 0h`), it's still not working. Although, I don't even see the need to clear the `ah` register because it's never set in the first place (unless the higher registers utilize it and my understanding is wrong).

Comment: It may be worth telling you that I defined `quot` in the .bss section as `quot resb 1`.

Comment: `ax` is made up of `al` and `ah`, and `eax` is made up of `ax` and 16 other bits.

Comment: I just realized my input numbers are two bytes, so I'm going to need to use the two byte DIV rule. One thing I still don't know is how to put the value of `num1` (the dividend) into both the `DX` and the `AX` registers. Can someone provide an explanation?

Comment: @CrAzYPiLoT: There isn't a separate signal for integer division exceptions.  If it sends a signal at all, [POSIX requires it to be SIGFPE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio).