# GCC: static data member optimized out in the debug build

Tags: c++, gcc, debug-information

Consider the following simple code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int v = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base<int> {};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

I compile it with GCC (8.3.0, 9.1.0, `g++ -g -O0 test.cpp`), then run GDB to examine the value of `d`:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = {<Base<int>> = {static v = <optimized out>}, <No data fields>}
```

`d.v` is gone... I tried to use `-ggdb`, `-ggdb3`, `-fvar-tracking` with no success.

If I compile with clang (`clang++ -g -O0 test.cpp`), I see the expected result:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = {<Base<int>> = {static v = 0}, <No data fields>}
```

This output is also seen with GCC if `Base` is not a template class:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = {<Base> = {static v = 0}, <No data fields>}
```

Where did `d.v` go? Why was it optimized out? Is it possible to prevent this optimization without modifying the source code?

Comment: you never access the value, it is nowhere referenced. Why should it be part of any code?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/lf3pkz here you can see that the whole program is simply a `return 0;`, so everything is optimized away.

Comment: `constexpr` values are supposed to be compile-time constants, so unless you [ODR-use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) them there's no need to keep it in the generated code.

Comment: @mch, this is also true for clang, but with clang I can still see the value of `d.v`.

Comment: @Klaus, because it is a non-optimized build with debug info in it. If `Base` is not a template, I can see the value of `d.v`, though it is never accessed and nowhere referenced.

Comment: @mch Are you sure it's nowhere in [here](https://godbolt.org/z/X8bPKi)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc -O0 still optimizes out "unused" code. Is there a compile flag to change that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832958/gcc-o0-still-optimizes-out-unused-code-is-there-a-compile-flag-to-change-tha)

Comment: @Klaus, I don't see how it answers my question. Both GCC and Clang optimize everything out, but Clang keeps some debug info that GCC doesn't. This question is not about code optimization, but about debug info in the compiled binary. I removed a misleading tag.

Comment: @Klaus, the fact that my simple program does nothing is absolutely irrelevant. This is just a minimal example. My real code does a lot of things, but some values (that are never accessed in the code) are still optimized out. The fact is that Clang keeps the info I want, and GCC doesn't, but only for class templates. Microsoft compiler also keeps that information. So, the 'efforts' argument is not very compelling. What is useless in an optimized build, is not always useless in a debug one, even if it is not accessed directly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesn't have to respect it, by using `constexpr` and providing an initialized value, you're strongly hinting to the compiler that it should constant-fold Base::v.

Gcc has a `-fkeep-static-consts`  flag that might do what you want.

Comment: Tried to compile with `-O0 -g -fkeep-static-consts`, and I'm still getting `<optimized out>`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce what you had, but I didn't have any luck getting it to allocate for 0. The dumb bit is that if I initialize a top-level global int to zero? Doesn't optimize it out. It's something about being in that struct that makes it impossible to not optimize