# Division by zero in processor

Tags: cpu-architecture, integer-division

How exactly does the processor handle this division by zero condition?

> A divide by zero condition occurs when in a divide operation the
> divisor turns out to be a zero as there is no binary representation for
> infinity. The ALU cannot handle it.

Does different processor have different way of handling it?
I am a new at this topic and all the articles on the Internet contradict other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the ISA. For example, x86 raises a #DE exception (same as divide overflow when the quotient doesn't fit in one register).  ARM doesn't fault, you just get `0` in the destination.  [Division by zero not causing runtime exception on Nvidia Jetson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57894010).

(ARM division instructions only have a dividend 1 register wide, unlike x86 where the dividend is twice as wide as the divisor or quotient.  ARM division can thus only overflow on INT_MIN/-1, other than divide-by-zero.)

In terms of an ALU, you have to build one that checks for that and handles it as a special case.  What the rest of the CPU's internal logic does

(I'm assuming you mean integer division; FP usually runs with exceptions masked...)

---

What the OS does with a division exception depends on the OS.  But if it's Unix-like, it has to deliver SIGFPE (arithmetic exception) to the offending process.  Of course at that point it's no longer CPU-architecture, but software.

- [On which platforms does integer divide by zero trigger a floating point exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio)
- [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe) (ARM vs. x86 difference)