How does division by zero works in C++?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "main started";
    int a = 10, b = 0;
    cout << a/b;
    cout << "main ending";
}

The above written C++ code is not printing anything on online compiler when run on "OnlineGDB" with C++ 20 vesion.
But the same program when run on g++-14 compiler from homebrew it produces
main started0main ending
I am not getting why?

dividing by zero is undefined.  You have undefined behavior.

If you change cout to cerr, you might see different output in the first case...

Does this answer your question? Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior

Inconsistent results is common for undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Division by zero is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.
[expr.pre]/4:

If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.


Practically what you usually see on a PC is a floating point exception signal and the program exiting because you didn't supply a handler telling it to do something else. In most cases crashing the program is a good thing. Div by zero is almost always a bug, and you want to make it as loud a s possible so you can catch the mistake before the customers do.

@user4581301 How can there be a FPE without a floating point involved in the example code?

@WeijunZhou Silly, eh? I think they just needed somewhere to hang div by zero, and FPE made the most sense at the time.

OK. That means you can get an FPE even after fedisableexcept(). I'll keep that in mind.

@user4581301 FPE requirement may be true for POSIX, but at least on Windows, MSVC (both for x86 and x64) does emit 0xC0000094 (integer division by zero). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37262572/1458097

@user4581301 sillier than it could be, because floating point division normally doesn't produce exception :P

@heapunderrun that's not feature of platform, that's  compiler and runtime library does what wasn't asked. Usually a debug version of it, and it's not mandatory - can be disabled both in compile time (do not generate calls) and probably in run-time (a lot of envirnment variables  control execution)
