# 8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I was helping a friend of mine debug his program, and we narrowed it down to an issue which occurs even here:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 16
.CODE
start:
    mov ax, 044c0h
    mov bl, 85
    idiv bl
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

end start
```

After assembling it with tasm 4.1, and running it on DOSBox 0.74, it goes into an infinite loop. When inspecting it with turbo debugger one can see it happens after the `idiv` instruction, which for some reason modifies the `cs` and `ip` registers, and after two seemingly random instructions restores them to point to the `idiv` line, executing it again ad infinitum.

Does anyone have any explanation for this?

Comment: Because the signed quotient of your division can't fit in an 8-bit register (_AL_) so you are getting an arithmetic overflow. The range for the quotient on a r16/r8 [IDIV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) is −128 to +127 . Your division yields a quotient of 207.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  Yep.  I was just about to submit that as an answer, but you beat me!

Comment: That would be the INT 00h interrupt handler. A bit surprising to me that it just jumps right back to the broken code, causing an infinite loop. I would have expected it to terminate the app, print an error message, or something a bit more obvious. You're the second person in as many days to be confused by this.

Comment: The divide overflow is the same exception as divide by zero.  You should either set up exception handling or guard against overflows by using 16 bit operations.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I didn't think of that aspect of the operation. Still new to assembly. Simply making it a word division instead should fix it right?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522230/div-instruction-jumping-to-random-location/43540860#43540860), but skip the rant at the top. :-) Or just go straight to [the documentation](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html). `DIV` and `IDIV` are kind of funky in x86, with their implicit operands.

Comment: Yeah, the other question didn't use IDIV. Probably best not to overcomplicate things. Feel free to post an answer here, @michael.

Comment: A possible canonical duplicate (for other questions, not this) for 8-bit `div` without zeroing AH [Assembly Divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38788694)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is a variation on other division related failures. The [`x86` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has some additional links:

> - **`idiv` / `div` problems**:  [Zero `edx` first, or sign-extend `eax` into it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416593/why-should-edx-be-0-before-i-use-div-opcode/38416896#38416896).  32bit `div` faults if the 64b/32b => 32b quotient doesn't actually fit in 32b.

---

The apparently random code your debugger seems to jump to is the Arithmetic Exception handler (also the same one as Divide by Zero). What is happening is that your code is experiencing a `Division Overflow`. You are doing a 16-bit/8-bit [*IDIV*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html). From the documentation:

> Signed divide AX by r/m8, with result stored in: AL ← Quotient, AH ← Remainder.

[image]

You will notice that for division with an 8-bit divisor (in your case *BL*) the range for the quotient is -128 to +127. 044c0h *IDIV* 85 is 207 (decimal). 207 doesn't fit in a signed 8-bit register so you get division overflow and the cause of your unexpected problem.

To resolve this you can move up to a 16-bit divisor. So you can place your divisor in *BX* (16-bit register). That would be `mov bx, 85`. Unfortunately it isn't so simple. When using a 16-bit divisor the processor assumes the dividend is 32-bits with high 16-bits in *DX* and lower 16-bits in *AX*.

> Signed divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX ← Quotient, DX ← Remainder.

To resolve this you have to sign extend the 16-bit value in *AX*. This is simple as you only need to use the [*CWD*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CWD:CDQ:CQO.html) instruction after placing the value in *AX*. From the instruction set reference

> DX:AX ← sign-extend of AX.

Effectively if the Most Significant Bit (MSB) of *AX* is 0 *DX* will become 0. If the MSB is 1 then *DX* would become 0ffffh (all bits set to one). The sign bit of a number is the MSB.

With all this in mind your division code could be adjusted to take a 16-bit divisor:

```
mov ax, 044c0h
cwd                ; Sign extend AX into DX (DX:AX = 32-bit dividend)
mov bx, 85         ; Divisor is 85
idiv bx            ; Signed divide of DX:AX by BX
```

Comment: Related: [Problems dividing 64 bits in x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22596059) has a version of the table of what goes where for all sizes from 8 to 64-bit, for unsigned div.